# Docker Entrypoint error while invoking lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker

I have a simple dockerfile, I'm trying to deploy my project with aws cdk but getting errors when I invoke the the deployed lambda func

```
ARG FUNCTION_DIR="/tmp/"

FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.10.2023.03.21.20-arm64 as build-image


# Include global arg in this stage of the build
ARG FUNCTION_DIR

# Create function directory
RUN mkdir -p ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Copy handler function
COPY query/*.py ${FUNCTION_DIR}
COPY prompt/*.py ${FUNCTION_DIR}
COPY starter ${FUNCTION_DIR}
COPY requirements-app.txt ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Install the function's dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip uninstall --yes jupyter
RUN pip install awslambdaric
RUN pip install --target ${FUNCTION_DIR} sentencepiece protobuf
RUN pip install -r ${FUNCTION_DIR}requirements-app.txt

FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.10.2023.03.21.20-arm64

# Include global arg in this stage of the build
ARG FUNCTION_DIR
# Set working directory to function root directory
WORKDIR ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Copy in the built dependencies
COPY --from=build-image ${FUNCTION_DIR} ${FUNCTION_DIR}

ENTRYPOINT [ "python", "-m", "awslambdaric" ]

# This will get replaced by the proper handler by the CDK script
CMD [ "will_be_replaced" ]
```

when I do cdk deploy and invoke lambda

I get error:

```
2023-03-23T13:31:36.066+05:30   /var/lang/bin/python: No module named awslambdaric

2023-03-23T13:31:36.138+05:30   /var/lang/bin/python: No module named awslambdaric

2023-03-23T13:31:36.142+05:30   START RequestId: f3e3d93b-3x4b-4dd6-5db1-2cldb63cdc70 Version: $LATEST
```

Expected: lambda runs successfully

Comment: Your python code is in a folder, who's name is stored in `$FUNCTION_DIR`. Your entrypoint python command is not running in that folder, so it can't find your code.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. It would be of great help if someone can help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76508986/aws-python-docker-base-image-via-gitlab-pipeline-raises-error?noredirect=1#comment134901898_76508986

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is in awslambdaric installation. According to the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/awslambdaric/), you should install it to `${FUNCTION_DIR}`, because you need to copy this installation to the second container during the multi-stage build. So it should look like:

```
RUN pip install \
    --target ${FUNCTION_DIR} \
        awslambdaric
```

I was able to invoke the Lambda function with your image after I changed awslambdaric installation target.