# AWS python docker base image via gitlab pipeline raises error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker

I have followed the [offical documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-image.html) for using the `AWS base python` recommended image but I am getting an unexpected error which is related to non-aws base python docker images. I did a POC where the image works fine but when I deploy the code as the docker image and create a lambda function out of it it throws an error. I am using `gitlab` pipeline for CI/CD. Below is my dockerfile code:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

# Install the function's dependencies using file requirements.txt
# from your project folder.

COPY requirements.txt  .

RUN  pip3 install -r requirements.txt --target ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}; \
     bash -c 'mkdir -p ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/{services,api} && mkdir -p ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/services/resources'; \
     yum update -y ; \
     yum install git -y

# Copy function code
COPY src/api/lambda_handler.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
COPY src/api/constants.py src/api/controller.py src/api/handler.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/api/
COPY src/services/*.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/services/
COPY src/services/resources/dag.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/services/resources/


# Set the CMD to your handler (could also be done as a parameter override outside of the Dockerfile)
CMD [ "lambda_handler.handler" ]
```

Now, this raises an unidentifiable error when I hit the lambda function via `API gateway`:

```
Endpoint response body before transformations: 

    {"errorType":"Runtime.ExitError","errorMessage":"RequestId: a8ebb6f3-sa Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1"}
```

and when I check logs it shows the below:

[image]

I also tried adding the below line in the `RUN` command of the dockerfile but no luck.

```
python3.8 -m pip --no-cache-dir install awslambdaric;
```

I am using the `gitlab` pipeline to build and push the image and the lambda function is created via `Terraform`. Below is the gitlab stage code:

```
docker_stage:
  image: docker:23.0.6
  stage: docker_stage
  services:
    - docker:23.0.6-dind
  script:
    - cd provisioner
    - apk add python3
    - python3 -m ensurepip --upgrade
    - pip3 install --upgrade pip
    - pip3 install awscli
    - docker build -t dbtsample .
    - docker tag dbtsample:latest <account-id>.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dbtsample:latest
    - aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-west-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <account-id>.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
    - docker push <account-id>.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dbtsample:latest
```

Also, below is the terraform code for creating the lambda function:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "api_lambda" {
  function_name = local.lambda_name
  timeout       = 300
  image_uri     = "${local.account_id}.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dbtsample:latest"
  package_type  = "Image"
  architectures = ["x86_64"]
  memory_size   = 1024
  role          = aws_iam_role.api_lambda_role.arn


  vpc_config {
    security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.security_group_for_lambda.id]
    subnet_ids         = var.subnet_ids
  }

  environment {
    variables = {
      gitlab_username     = var.gitlab_username
      gitlab_access_token = var.gitlab_access_token
    }
  }
}
```

Also, I would like to highlight that the docker image which is used in the gitlab stage is `alpine linux` and the Python installed through the commands is `3.10` (that's what comes with that specific alpine version) and my project has been built over `Python 3.8` but I don't think so that would make any difference because I am just installing Python to install `awscli` module but just an FYI.

Also, as suggested by Pierre in the comments, when I checked the list of packages installed I see the below list:

[image]

What else am I missing here?

Comment: what's output when you RUN : `python3 -m pip --no-cache-dir install awslambdaric;`

Comment: It installs the specified library along with some extra json package which comes with that library.  @ThanhNguyenVan

Comment: As per the documentation, `awslambdaric` is required only if we use images other than base images. So in my case, I am not supposed to run it actually.

Comment: How to define `LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT` in Dockerfile ?

Comment: what do you mean? It is already defined.

Comment: try to change it `CMD [ "lambda_handler.lambda_handler" ]` to `CMD [ "lambda_handler.handler" ]`

Comment: Inside my lambda_handler.py there is a method called as lambda_handler. Therefore I have it as `lambda_handler.lambda_handler`

Comment: Is there something that I can do for `awslambdaric` via entrypoint or something? But if I define entrypoint, I won't be able to use it for the `lambda`.

Comment: I have added more context to the question.

Comment: Strange, looks like you added everything necessary to have `lambdaric`. Check your image is built correctly by running locally: `docker run -it --entrypoint sh <account-id>.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dbtsample:latest` and run in container `pip3 list` to check you have `awslambdaric` installed (you can also try `python -c "import awslambdaricz"`)

Comment: I have also added some context at the end of the post and modified my `Dockerfile` code.

Comment: @PierreB. Okay thanks for that. I checked and even after using this command `pip3 install awslambdaric --target ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}; \` I don't see the `awslambdaric` module in the list. But why do I need that? I am using a base image.

Comment: @PierreB. I have added the list of packages in the question

Comment: Have you test using the 3.10 base image?

Comment: No but I don't see any differences mentioned on the documentation @ErikAsplund

Comment: No you are right, but the base image should come with the package and it seems like it is not, so may be worth a try.

Comment: Also, I developed a `hello-world` image which works fine via Lambda using the same docker image i.e `python 3.8` then why do I need the `RIC` for this particular repo I am not sure about that. Can somebody enlighten me on this?

Comment: @ErikAsplund I will try not a problem but my project is developed in `3.8` and also as I mentioned in my last comment it works fine for the `hello-world`.

Comment: @ErikAsplund Same error. Doesn't work with other Python base images too. It's weird that it works for the `hello-world` problem and the same exact code doesn't work when deployed via the gitlab pipeline.

Comment: I have posted my answer. Thank you all for all the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was related to the ECR repo. What I think is some docker image layers weren't updated even if the `Dockerfile` code was updated. So, I entirely deleted the ECR repo and created a new repo, and passed that into the `gitlab-ci.yml` stage and it worked like a charm. I used the AWS base image only but ensure that the runtime is included by running `docker run -it --entrypoint sh image-name > ls` locally and by pulling the remote image. Also, I had to explicitly use the below command in the Dockerfile:

```
RUN pip install awslambdaric --target ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
```

Just before the function code.

Also, I think the **docker build** command can be improved in order to ensure that the ECR repo is picking up the correct image only.

So something like:

```
docker build -t dbt_image:$CI_COMMIT_SHA


docker tag dbt_image:$CI_COMMIT_SHA <account-id>.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dbtsample:latest
```